# Convert binary data from URL to an image file

Tags: image, binary-data

I read several articles on StackOverflow, but none of them seems to work in my case so here is the situation.

I have a webpage that is not under my control. It contains an image that is referenced in the markup as something like `<img src="getimage.asp?pic=4c54aae0ea..." />`. Given the URL of that image, I would like to download it, save it to disk and do something with it.

When I enter the URL directly in my browser I get a binary stream. This is the first load of characters.

```
ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿþLEAD Technologies Inc. V1.01ÿÛ„ÿÄ¢       }!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚     %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #
```

How do I convert that data to an image using e.g. C# or any other language. Since I do not control the page I have no idea of how the data is encoded - so can I still decode it?

As can be seen from the first couple of characters, the string "LEAD Technologies Inc." is included in the data so I guess its not all image data. But at least, Chrome obviously knows how to decode it. A quick Google check reveals that "LEAD technologies" is an imaging SDK, but their website doesn't seem to offer much information about it's use and Im also not proficient in image manipulation. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it is all image data. JPEG files can have embedded metadata in them, and generally their inner structure is quite messy. You can tell that it's a JPEG because there are `JFIF` letters in the beginning.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, but how to save it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first couple of characters indicate that the response is probably an jpeg file interpreted as ASCII text. I guess the `Content-Type` header in the HTTP response has the wrong value, probably something like `text/plain` or `text/html` instead of `image\jpeg`. This makes Chrome display the image as plain text.

I don't think you have to convert the data. Just save the response stream to a file and you will have a proper jpeg file:

```
string url = "http://my-domain/getimage.asp?pic=4c54aae0ea...";
string fileLocation = @"C:\MyImage.jpg";

var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, fileLocation);
```

The reason I think that the response is probably jpeg, is that a jpeg file begins with `0xFFD8FFE0` which looks like `ÿØÿà` when displayed as `ISO 8859-1` encoded text.

Comment: Ok. Got it. But simply downloading and saving the data as you suggest with your code sample saves only a small jpg file with grey background and the text "No photo available" written on it. Any other ideas?

Comment: And I know that the URL carries image data, because I saw it in the browser :)

Comment: By the way, creating a simple HTML document with only an image element with href attribute set to the URL directly renders the same image as the one downloaded by the above code.."no photo available". Could it be that the original web page uses some kind of encoding behind the scenes?

I also checked the request that is sent to the server when the URL is opened directly in the browser and the server returns MIME type text/html

Comment: Update: If I open up the page source of the page that owns the photo and I click the url in the href attribute while holding ALT in Chrome (to download file), Chrome downloads the URL as an htm file. If I rename that file from XX.htm to XX.jpg I get a perfectly fine picture! 

But how is that different from the code above where the file is downloaded with the WebClient object?

Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Johnson. Sometimes a website prevents you from downloading an image by checking for a session cookie or by checking the http referer header (yes, one 'r'). You can add the referer header to the `Headers` collection of the `WebClient` object.

Comment: I tried adding this without any luck.. client.Headers.Add("Referer: <url>"); Nice idea though!

Comment: Ok, so I made a mistake in the code. It works now. Fantastic! It was the header that needed the referer entry. Thank you! Briliant answer.